# Find duplicate file use cmp command

Tags: linux, bash

I would to write a bash script to find duplicate files but I don't want just use md5sum.
It means, in addition to use md5sum I want to check my files with cmp command.

I use the command below for finding duplicate files. Right now I need to write a loop and use cmp command for finding duplicates. How can I write a loop and write a bash script?

```
find . -type f | xargs -I%  md5sum % | sort | uniq -w32 -D| cut  -f3 -d' '
```

Comment: what is leading you to do `cmp` in addition of `md5sum` ? Are you afraid of hash collision ?

Comment: No this is my assignment and i have to write a bash script and find duplicate file

Comment: Question also exists on [unix&linux SE](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/22085/4667)

Answer (score 2):

Give this [short introduction to Bash](http://www.codecoffee.com/tipsforlinux/articles2/043.html) a look.

If you wrote the one-liner in your question, the first part will be quite boring for you, but you can just skip to the **Control structures** section. The basic tools for flow control (if/for/while/do...while) are described there, with nice examples.